# Catch Exception in Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

How can I set the expectancy of an exception to be thrown in a test in Clojure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(is (thrown? NumberFormatException (Integer/parseInt "49FREN")))
```

Comment: thanks! just after publishing this I found it in the API documentation X{D

Comment: Relevant documentation, [`is`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.test/is) and [API for clojure.test](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html).